# How to slide down a stateless component in React JS using ReactCSStransitionGroup or ReactTransitionGroup?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions, react-transition-group

I want to slide a stateless component, which will be initially set to `display:none`, to be visible after state change in one of its parent component, as if it is slide down just like a dropdown.
I am new to animation part, I was trying out [this_link](https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html#getting-started).

So far what i tried in Sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/0xrjp051pp).

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified Sandbox with the transition working. https://codesandbox.io/s/nrz8vlmrrl The only thing that you need to fix is the CSS code to get it to work a desired.

The changes I made are as follows.

1. Changed the transition class in CSS to display the component. It had display:none previously.
2. Show and hide the component based on the prop that you were passing but not using in your component `SubComponent`.

Comment: This works like normal `display:block` and `display:none`. I want the component to slide and get displayed. Just like how a dropdown slides down slowly. Tried with @keyframes css, But its not working.